# После установки java centos insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, centos

Долго не запускалась `java` на `vds centos` последней версии, ошибка:

> insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to continue could not
>   reserve enough space for object heap java version

Долго мучился и разные версии ставил и решения разные, пока не нашел совет один в интернете убрать ограничение ресурсов командой:

```
ulimit -v unlimited
```

Или же `ulimit -Sv ...` в файл  `/etc/profile` чтоб навсегда.

> ENGLISH ERROR: insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to
>   continue could not reserve enough space for object heap java version
>   English fix: "ulimit -v unlimited"
>
> which is done every time we log in. Alternatively, we can also comment
>   out the line
>
> "ulimit -Sv ..."
>
> in /etc/profile, which is a more permanent solution.

Comment: Это вопрос или самоответ?

Answer (score 1):

Долго мучился и разные версии ставил и решения разные пока не нашел совет один в интернете убрать ограничение ресурсов коммандой: ulimit -v unlimited Или же ulimit -Sv ... в файл /etc/profile чтоб навсегда.

ENGLISH ERROR: insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to continue could not reserve enough space for object heap java version English fix: "ulimit -v unlimited"

which is done every time we log in. Alternatively, we can also comment out the line

"ulimit -Sv ..."

in /etc/profile, which is a more permanent solution.